# Primes that are product of distinct primes plus one

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers

Primorial primes are the primes that are of the form $p_n \# \pm 1$, where $p_n \#$ is the product of first $n$ primes.

My doubt is follows:

Is there **any special name or study** for the primes of the form $2p_1p_2p_3\cdots p_n + 1$,where $p_1, p_2 \cdots p_n$ are distinct odd primes but not necessarily the first $n$ primes?

Comment: You could call them "prime distinctorials".

Comment: To help narrow things down before running an OEIS search, note that there are no primes of the form $4k + 1$ in your "distinctorials" $\mathcal P$ since $\mu(\mathcal P - 1) \neq 0$.

Comment: "radical primes" could be a good name as well...

Answer (score 2):

I think [A039787](https://oeis.org/A039787) might be what you are looking for. On OEIS, they are called "*Primes p such that p-1 is squarefree.*". At first glance, there doesn't seem to be much research on these primes.

[A075430](https://oeis.org/A075430) and [A049097](https://oeis.org/A049097) are also relevant.